# Rotating a view in Android

Tags: android, view, rotation

I have a button that I want to put on a 45 degree angle. For some reason I can't get this to work.

Can someone please provide the code to accomplish this?

Comment: a simple solution ,answered by @Michale works like charm  :)
One line in XML
<View
    android:rotation="45"
    ... />

Comment: You are right @Muahmmad, but it will only help if you want to do it from xml,but if we want to do it dynamically like on button click then it will not work..

Answer (score 74):

API 11 added a [setRotation()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setRotation%28float%29) method to all views.

Comment: @GerhardBarnard setRotation() is the method to use and is the answer itself. The link is only there for convenience.

Answer (score 60):

You could create an animation and apply it to your button view. For example:

```
    // Locate view
    ImageView diskView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView3);

    // Create an animation instance
    Animation an = new RotateAnimation(0.0f, 360.0f, pivotX, pivotY);

    // Set the animation's parameters
    an.setDuration(10000);               // duration in ms
    an.setRepeatCount(0);                // -1 = infinite repeated
    an.setRepeatMode(Animation.REVERSE); // reverses each repeat
    an.setFillAfter(true);               // keep rotation after animation

    // Aply animation to image view
    diskView.setAnimation(an);
```

Comment: Nice to see that things that can't be done defining layouts can be achieved with animations and setFillAfter(true).

Comment: This will rotate the view all right, but buttons wont have their functionality rotated. Not the holy grail for me :)

Comment: It turns out that there isn't any way to rotate functionality of a button. I ended up forwarding events to the buttons based on where the screen was touched.

Answer (score 47):

Extend the `TextView` class and override the `onDraw()` method.  Make sure the parent view is large enough to handle the rotated button without clipping it.

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
     canvas.save();
     canvas.rotate(45,<appropriate x pivot value>,<appropriate y pivot value>);
     super.onDraw(canvas);
     canvas.restore();

}
```

Comment: Ok that sorta accomplish's what i want. I want the entire view itself to be on a 45 degree angle. Just not the text inside. But thank you for answering my question

Comment: If you want to rotate the entire view (along with its background), you should oveerride draw() instead of onDraw().

Comment: ok it works if using draw()method rotate the whole button but not drawing view correctly

Comment: There is no need to save whole canvas state,  canvas.save(Canvas.MATRIX_SAVE_FLAG) is enough.

Answer (score 30):

I just used the simple line in my code and it works :

```
myCusstomView.setRotation(45);
```

Hope it works for you.

Comment: Note: this method is available since API 11 (Honeycomb)

Comment: after rotating the view(ImageView) is it possible to save the image with that rotation??

Answer (score 27):

**One line in XML**

---

```
<View
    android:rotation="45"
    ... />
```

Answer (score 23):

Applying a rotation animation (without duration, thus no animation effect) is a simpler solution than either calling View.setRotation() or override View.onDraw method.

```
// substitude deltaDegrees for whatever you want
RotateAnimation rotate = new RotateAnimation(0f, deltaDegrees, 
    Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f);  

// prevents View from restoring to original direction. 
rotate.setFillAfter(true); 

someButton.startAnimation(rotate);
```

Answer (score 7):

Rotating view with `rotate()` will not affect your view's measured size. As result, rotated view be clipped or not fit into the parent layout. This library fixes it though:

https://github.com/rongi/rotate-layout

[image]

Comment: this is nice work but if the control is wider than screen size? how to make it fit to screen?

Answer (score 6):

Joininig @Rudi's and @Pete's answers. I have created an RotateAnimation that keeps buttons functionality also after rotation.

setRotation() method preserves buttons functionality.

Code Sample:

```
Animation an = new RotateAnimation(0.0f, 180.0f, mainLayout.getWidth()/2, mainLayout.getHeight()/2);

    an.setDuration(1000);              
    an.setRepeatCount(0);                     
    an.setFillAfter(false);              // DO NOT keep rotation after animation
    an.setFillEnabled(true);             // Make smooth ending of Animation
    an.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {}

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {}

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                mainLayout.setRotation(180.0f);      // Make instant rotation when Animation is finished
            }
            }); 

mainLayout.startAnimation(an);
```

mainLayout is a (LinearLayout) field

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned before, the easiest way it to use `rotation` available since API 11:

```
android:rotation="90"    // in XML layout

view.rotation = 90f      // programatically
```

You can also change pivot of rotation, which is by default set to center of the view. This needs to be changed programatically:

```
// top left
view.pivotX = 0f
view.pivotY = 0f

// bottom right
view.pivotX = width.toFloat()
view.pivotY = height.toFloat()

...
```

In Activity's `onCreate()` or Fragment's `onCreateView(...)` width and height are equal to 0, because the view wasn't measured yet. You can access it simply by using `doOnPreDraw` extension from [Android KTX](https://developer.android.com/kotlin/ktx), i.e.:

```
view.apply {
    doOnPreDraw {
        pivotX = width.toFloat()
        pivotY = height.toFloat()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

if you wish to make it dynamically with an animation:

```
view.animate()
    .rotation(180)
    .start();
```

THATS IT

Answer (score 1):

@Ichorus's answer is correct for views, but if you want to draw rotated rectangles or text, you can do the following in your onDraw (or onDispatchDraw) callback for your view:

(note that theta is the angle from the x axis of the desired rotation, pivot is the Point that represents the point around which we want the rectangle to rotate, and horizontalRect is the rect's position "before" it was rotated)

```
canvas.save();
canvas.rotate(theta, pivot.x, pivot.y);
canvas.drawRect(horizontalRect, paint);
canvas.restore();
```

Answer (score 1):

That's simple,
in Java

```
your_component.setRotation(15);
```

or

```
your_component.setRotation(295.18f);
```

in XML

```
<Button android:rotation="15" />
```

Answer (score 1):

```
fun rotateArrow(view: View): Boolean {
    return if (view.rotation == 0F) {
        view.animate().setDuration(200).rotation(180F)
        true
    } else {
         view.animate().setDuration(200).rotation(0F)
         false
    }
}
```