# Rotate an Android ImageView AND its background

Tags: android, rotation, imageview

Using [this mechanism](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1930963/rotating-a-view-in-android) I'm able to successfully rotate the image in an ImageView.  Works great.

However, if the ImageView has a background image, that drawable is not also rotated.  How can I also rotate the background image of an ImageView?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Overwrite draw() instead of onDraw() to rotate the background.

```
@Override
public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
    canvas.save();
    canvas.rotate(45,xRotation,yRotation);
    super.draw(canvas);
    canvas.restore();
}
```

Comment: Thx ! Is there a way to enable anti aliasing on this rotation ?

Answer (score 2):

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity
{
    private ImageView mImageView = null;
    private Animation mRotateAnimation = null;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        mImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.my_image);
        mRotateAnimation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.my_rotate_90);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            mImageView.startAnimation(mRotateAnimation);
            return true;
        }
        return super.onTouchEvent(event);
    }
}
```