# Android rotate control

Tags: android, controls, rotation

How to rotate control (checkbox) in 180 or 90 degrees ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way is roughly the same as in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1930963/rotating-a-view-in-android):

```
public class CheckBox90 extends CheckBox {
    public CheckBox90(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        canvas.rotate(90,20,20);
        super.onDraw(canvas);
    }
}
```

...but that's kind of hacky. Probably better to do it [this way](http://www.anddev.org/tutorial_change_look_of_checkbox-t4553.html). Grab the checkbox images, rotate them in the image editor of your choice, then tell Android to use the rotated versions.

Comment: How to call in main program (what to type in main.xml) ?

Comment: thanks, thanks, thanks... :) I don't have much points to vote for the your post :)

Comment: I'd argue that the hacky way you described is actually better than creating new images - that way, if the whole has a different look and feel and custom checkbox images, the app will use those instead of rotated versions of the standard Android checkboxes. And user346665 - you should be able to mark Daniel's post as the "best answer".

Comment: The problem with the hacky way is that I had to play around to figure out which pivot point offset to use - in this case, (20, 20). If the GUI element size changes, those numbers will probably have to change - which is bad. I'm not sure if there's a way to programmatically determine what pivot point to use, as I didn't spend that time researching it, but there may be.