# How to change a default Horizontal ProgressBar to vertical?

Tags: java, android

So far i have a working horizontal progress bar.

This is my xml file

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progressBar1"
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="168dp" />
```

I'm going to use it as a visual indicator of a liquid tank.(Progress as level)

I want to know how to set it vertcal. If it is not possible can some one suggest some other option to my problem.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3926395/android-set-a-progressbar-to-be-a-vertical-bar-instead-of-horizontal, may be helpful :)