# Android FrameLayout with image slide in

Tags: android, imageview, android-framelayout

I need to create a gauge. The first image will be static and holds the measurements and markings. The second image will slide in from bottom to top. To simulate a water tank.

What will be the best way to handle this problem?

At the moment I am trying to use a framelayout to hold the two images but not sure if its the right approach.

I have done this in css and jquery but cant seen to find a way around it in android native.

any ideas?

Comment: Tried with a seekbar ? Or a 9-patch png image ?

Comment: Can you put the code that you are using current?

Answer (score 0):

In general you'll have better luck here if you make the title of your question more descriptive. It doesn't seem like you are actually asking anything about FrameLayout.

Anywho, if I am understanding you correctly you should be able to adapt [ProgressBar](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ProgressBar.html) to fit your needs for creating a water tank. Note if you want it to be vertical instead of horizontal you can find a solution on this question: [Android - set a ProgressBar to be a vertical bar instead of horizontal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3926395/android-set-a-progressbar-to-be-a-vertical-bar-instead-of-horizontal)

Comment: progress bar does not match the second image width.

Comment: You can set the width of progress bar to whatever you want. Can you post the code that you are trying?