# Inclined EditText in Android?

Tags: android, android-edittext

I want to display editext which is slightly inclined not completely horizontal. Does anyone know how can I do that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Rotating a view in android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1930963/rotating-a-view-in-android)

Answer (score 0):

You can use Canvas.rotate() before drawing the text. You should call `save()` before rotating, and then `restore()` afterwards.

If you want an inclined baseline but the letters vertical (not rotated), there's no API support for that. You're going to have to render each letter yourself and calculate the baseline shift from letter to letter in your own code.

Comment: can't Canvas.drawTextOnPath() be used for your second case? does it keep letters parallel to the path?

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think drawTextOnPath() rotates the each character to use a baseline that is tangent to the path at the point where the character is drawn. If that's right, it means that drawTextOnPath is a second way of doing the first case (by using a straight-line path set at the desired angle).