# Create custom widgets for android

Tags: android, layout, ondraw

I'm trying to create a rotating imageView. Looking at this (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1930963/rotating-a-view-in-android) I know I'll have to override onDraw.

But when I create my own derrived TextView class, how do I use it in my xml layouts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use it in your xml layout add the following:

```
<view class="yourpackage.yourclass.yourview" ...additional parameters... />
```

note the **lowercase** "view" or by directly specifying its name

```
<yourpackage.yourclass.yourview ...additional parameters... />
```

Answer (score 0):

How to create and access custom components is discussed here

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/custom-components.html