# Rotate button in onDraw()

Tags: android

I've tried [it this way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1930963/rotating-a-view-in-android) but this doesn't work. What am I doing wrong?

```
    RotateButton sdb = (RotateButton) findViewById(R.id.slideDown);
    sdb.invalidate(); //rotate
```

the class:

```
public class RotateButton extends Button    {

    public RotateButton (Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public RotateButton (Context context, AttributeSet set) {
        super(context, set);
    }


    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        canvas.save();
        Log.d("temp", "rotating");
        canvas.rotate(90);
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        canvas.restore();
        //requestLayout();
    }


}
```