# How to tilt a button along with its text...?

Tags: android, button, android-animation

I am new to android development, can any one tell me how to rotate entire a button into 45 degrees along with text and button rect. I want to rotate permanently and i want on click listener on the same.

Comment: Make your question more clear. Whether you want to rotate the button permanently and on what event(like on button click etc)..

Comment: There's a related question (where you will find your answer) here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1930963/rotating-a-view-in-android

Comment: @Dinesh  I want to rotate permanently and i want on click listener on the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use animations for that.

in your /res/anim/ you must create an xml file with this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<rotate
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:fromDegrees="0"
  android:toDegrees="45"
  android:pivotX="50%"
  android:pivotY="50%"
  android:duration="0"
  android:startOffset="0"
/>
```

and the in your Activity:

```
RotateAnimation ranim = (RotateAnimation)AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.YOUR_ANIM);
ranim.setFillAfter(true);
YourButton.setAnimation(ranim);
```

Apart from that it seems that there are some problems with diagonal rotations (a.k.a. 45 degrees) pre-honeycomb..

Comment: Are you sure that the Rotation animation will rotate the actual view rectangle.

Comment: Well I used it on my own app.. you can see an screenshot here.. https://ssl.gstatic.com/android/market/appinventor.ai_serpro.MTGDroid/ss-800-1-14 the buttons to add and subtract are the same but rotated. also the same with the horizontal ones.

Comment: I tried this but on click listener on the rotated button is not working.

Comment: I saw that problem yesterday in SO. The problem was that the OnClickListener worked on the top part, but not on the bottom.. and they found out that it's a pre-honeycomb problem.. is that your problem too?

Comment: Yes mine also OnClickListener is working only in the top part. how to resolve this problem...?

Comment: warning: duration is zero