# Android:How to rotate LinearLayout

Tags: java, android

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@drawable/bg2x" >
<LinearLayout 
    android:id="@+id/linear"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:background="#FF00FF00"
  >
    <TextView 

        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#FF000000"
        android:textSize="70dp"
        android:text="test linearlayout"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

Now I wanna **Rotate** the "**linear**" layout by 90 degrees. *** And I dont wanna use Animation***, is there any other way to achive this?
Please help me.Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Do you want to rotate it, in your XML... or programatically (i.e. onClick)?

Comment: Have you tried this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1930963/rotating-a-view-in-android ?

Comment: use android:rotation tag

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Since you don't need animation, from API 11 or above, you can use

```
android:rotation = "90"
```

to rotate in XML itself. If you want to do it in code, say after a button click, then you can use its java equalant too

```
 yourLayout  = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.your_id);
 yourLayout.setRotation(90.0f);
```

But not before API 11. See [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android:rotation).

> **android:rotation**
>
> rotation of the view, in degrees.
>
> Must be a floating point value, such as "1.2".
>
> This may also be a reference to a resource (in the form
>   "@[package:]type:name") or theme attribute (in the form
>   "?[package:][type:]name") containing a value of this type.
>
> This corresponds to the global attribute resource symbol rotation.

### EDIT: After seeing comment

> yeah,I know this method in API level 11. But what about lower api
>   level?

I think you can have to rotate the view yourselves. And I believe the lchorus and Pete's answer in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1930963/rotating-a-view-in-android) thread does work. For Pete's answer he is using animation, but you can set animation duration of 0 to do it without any visible animation. There is no other straight forward way as far as I know..

Comment: yeah,I know this method in API level 11. But what about lower api level? thanks

Answer (score 3):

Using this library you can rotate whole view hierarchy https://github.com/rongi/rotate-layout

Like this

[image]