# pulling drawer layout from icon at the bottom

Tags: android, android-layout, navigation-drawer

Drawer layouts are typically pulled from the action bar, at least per the official docs. Is there a way to have a pull ImageView attached to the bottom of the drawer? So that the user would tap or pull the ImageView to draw out the navigation drawer? I am referring to the docs at http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html#ActionBarIcon

Answer (score 0):

On newer devices you could try to rotate the view. But I don't know if this will work. See this answer [Android:How to rotate LinearLayout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13698733/androidhow-to-rotate-linearlayout)

Comment: rotation simply turns everything upside down.