# android: is there a way to horizontally flip a layout?

Tags: android

Is there a way to hit a button, and have the same layout view but flipped horizontally/mirrored ? (with all it's components)
or the only way is to create the same layout and rearrange the components?

Comment: I only know about rotation: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1930963/rotating-a-view-in-android

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can flip a layout by setting the View property `scaleX` to -1.  So `View#setScaleX(1f)` is normal, and `View#setScaleX(-1f)` is flipped (visually).

To do it pre-Honeycomb, you can use scale properties in the general Animation library.  Just set the animation duration to 0 for immediate look (note, the elements will still be in the normal locations).

Comment: Very nice and easy solution!

Answer (score 3):

You can use `setRotationY(float)` method to flip over the Y axis. If you would call `yourView.setRotationY(180f)` it would flip it horizontally. Similarly, `yourView.setRotationX(180f)` would flip it vertically.

Please note that it flips on a 3D space, so if you'd flip for 90f, your view will practically be invisible.

Comment: rotating instead of flipping view will also result in inside views to be vertically flipped.

Answer (score 0):

if you have a button that flips the view horizontally or vertically, you should add 180f to the view's rotation so that the button flips the view on the first click and restore the rotation on the second click.

Because 360 rotation is equal to 0 rotation.

```
TextView myTextView=findViewById(R.id.my_text_view);

button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
       @Override
       onClick(View v){

      myTextView.setRotationX(myTextView.getRotationX()+180f); //horizontal flip
    // myTextView.setRotationY(myTextView.getRotationY()+180f)  //vertical flip

}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try by adjusting gravity and rotation attribute of you container.