# How to horizontal flip my android screen, in order to see it like if i am watching it on a mirror?

Tags: android, rotation, screen, flip, mirror

i had a question while programming for android, i just want to know if there is a way to flip all my android app in order to see it like a mirror.

The main idea is to have my app flipped, in order to see it in a mirror , and that it looks normal for me after reflecting in the mirror.

Sorry if im not very specific, but any idea or documment will be apreciated,  also i dont know how to look for that information, so i couldnt look deeper for more information.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just use `setRotationY(180)`.

Comment: This post may be helpful:[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22262064/android-is-there-a-way-to-horizontally-flip-a-layout][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22262064/android-is-there-a-way-to-horizontally-flip-a-layout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## NOT a Mirror Effect:

I suggest another way:

Add **reverseLandscape** to manifest

```
<activity
        ...
        android:screenOrientation="reverseLandscape" />
```

This way statusbar will rotate too.

Comment: @CesarCisneros, it will not make exactly a "mirror effect", but it will rotate screen with statusbar 180 degrees