# Mirror/flip/swap system screen horizontally in Android

Tags: android

Is it possible to mirror the the rendered display/screen at OS level horizontally or vertically?

To be clear: I do not intend to rotate or transmit/cast a display content. I rather like to have a mirror image replacing the original one, being like a reflection of physical planar mirror.

The resulting screen should be application agnostic and allow any animations etc. The touch screen matrix is irrelevant (maybe mirrored or stay the same).

Potential use cases: Projection of an image over a reflecting surface. Imagine a Head-up display on a car pane/windshield or a Head-mounted display with mirrors.

I already checked

- /system/build.prop: allows density settings and rotation modifications.
- [View.setScaleX(-1f)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setScaleX%28float%29): scaling views

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29608684/how-to-horizontal-flip-my-android-screen-in-order-to-see-it-like-if-i-am-watchi

Comment: @JeanYang You referred to a rotation not a mirror projection.