# Android Horizontal View without changing Application View

Tags: android, android-layout

I have got a View in my Layout. I want to change the Bitmap and the Button to horizontal View, without changing the Application View. The Application is always in Vertical position, so it's doing nothing when I change the rotation.

How is this possible like in the picture bellow? I am not good at layouts, took me days to only do that thing bellow.

[image]

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:id="@+id/paint_colors"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

    </LinearLayout>

    <com.example.drawing.DrawingView
        android:id="@+id/drawing"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#FFFFFFFF" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/clear"
                android:layout_width="306dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#009fca"
                android:contentDescription="@string/clear"
                android:text="Do clear" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Rotating a view in android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1930963/rotating-a-view-in-android)

Comment: I'm not understanding your problem, what do you want to do exactly?, make your application able to rotate your screen? or rotate your layout having the device in a vertical position?

Comment: it should not rotate at runtime. it should be set up one time at the beginning, like the picture in my post shows. left one is current state, right one the result i want.

Comment: i think we can't do in xml or layout,you have to rotate at run time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in the xml layout you can use "rotation"

```
 <ImageView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:rotation="90"/>
```

or in your activity you can say

```
myImageView.setRotation(90);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal"

android:background="#FFFFFF"
 >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/front"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"

    android:orientation="horizontal"

    android:weightSum="100">


    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/thumb_wrapper"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"

        android:layout_weight="100">


        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/drawing"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:src="@drawable/restaurant_1"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:rotation="90"
            android:background="#FFFFFFFF" />



        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:background="#009fca"

            >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/clear"
                android:layout_width="90dip"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:background="#009fca"

                android:text="Do clear"
                android:rotation="90"


                />


        </RelativeLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```