# How to rotate something with animation in android

Tags: java, android, animation

I am new to android, and I was learning animation.
I figured out that we could use items in the selector and apply as a background.
How do I rotate an ImageView using animation?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Rotating a view in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1930963/rotating-a-view-in-android)

Comment: Hello, It's very close to my question but it's not exactly that.

Answer (score 0):

In a view (xml) you can use:

```
android:rotation="15" // that’s means 15 degrees
```

Programmatically: you can use rotation, for example a TextView

```
my_textview.rotation = 15F

//Animation:
my_textview.animate()
        .setDuration(600)
        .rotation(15f)
        .start()
```

Comment: Hello Azhagthott,  It did change the rotation, But this does not show an animation.

Comment: Ahh ok I think was my bad, I didn’t read that you want to create an animation, let me edit my answer