# How to constrain a rotated View/Button to the left side of ConstraintLayout on Android?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, rotation

*Edit: it is possible to just to use `translateX` (see comments and accepted answer). I don't know how I missed that.*

On Android, I want to rotate a simple button 90 degrees and have it stick against the left side of my ConstraintLayout. However, when I try this, there remains significant space between the left side of the screen and the button. This is what it should look like:

[image: desired outcome]

This is my XML layout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:rotation="90"
        android:text="My example button"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

And here is the Android Studio design view of what it actually looks like:

[image: wrong outcome]

This seems to be because the constraints to the left/start (and top and bottom) are applied first, and the rotation second. I have tried programmatically to fix this problem to no avail in Java:

```
Button button = view.findViewById(R.id.button);
button.setRotation(90); // already done, but doesn't matter

// constrain to left side after after rotation (doesn't help)
ConstraintSet constraintSet = new ConstraintSet();
constraintSet.clone((ConstraintLayout) view);
constraintSet.connect(button.getId(), ConstraintSet.START, ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID, ConstraintSet.START);
constraintSet.applyTo((ConstraintLayout) view);

// attempt to fix positioning with margins (doesn't move anything at all)
ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams params = (ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams) btnTest.getLayoutParams();
params.setMargins(-100, 0, 0, -100); // left, top, right, bottom
btnTest.setLayoutParams(params);
```

I also tried changing the margins in the XML layout file, which similarly has absolutely no effect. *Edit: it seems like using negative margins didn't work in my original project, but it does in a newer test project. I suspect this is caused by using old versions of some libraries (probably the material library which I'm implicitly using through appcompat 1.1.0).*

Does anyone know how to achieve the result I want?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: can you try `android:translationX` with a negative `dp` value?

Comment: Yep, that did it. The amount by which to translate seems to be `-width/2+height/2-insetBottom`, which is a bit annoying when I'm not setting the width, height and inset explicitly, but this does work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Contrary to your statement, `margin` works for me:

```
<button
      android:id="@+id/button"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_marginLeft="-65dp"
      android:rotation="90"
      android:text="My example button"
      app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

If you want to make the shift programmatically, the following solution also works for me:

```
button.setTranslationX(-195f);  // in pixels
```

Third possibility: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1930963/rotating-a-view-in-android/64806125#64806125) older solution.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Negative margins are not working in my project, probably because I'm using some old versions of libraries. I started a new sample project with newer libraries and then the negative margins do work.

Comment: I don't know why I didn't think of setting the translationX, but that is the solution I will now go with. It's not totally ideal, because it seems we need to translate by `-width/2+height/2-insetBottom`, and these are not easy to obtain when set implicitly through wrap_content, the width of the text, and the style of the button.

Comment: Yes, you are right, you have to do some calculations (by the way, also with the other two solutions). But you can calculate the width of the (original horizontal) button using `button.getPaint().measureText(...)`, even if the text changes. Good luck.

Comment: Maybe [this](https://github.com/rongi/rotate-layout) can help (I didn't try).

Comment: ... or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41526595/22820043)

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
        val button: Button = findViewById(R.id.button)
        button.pivotX = 125f
        button.rotation = 90f
        val params = button.layoutParams as ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams
        params.startToStart = ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams.PARENT_ID
        params.topToTop = ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams.PARENT_ID
        button.layoutParams = params
```

Set pivot before rotation. The pivot point defines the point around which the view is rotated. I have written in kotlin.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! A variation of this worked, although it seems I should set pivotX to 0, pivotY to some other number related to the button's height, and then I still have to do something to translate the button in order to vertically center it again. So just using translateX without the pivot stuff is simpler.

Answer (score 0):

I had commented before about using translate X property. Now I'm posting Java code for the same.

```
button.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
  @Override
  public void onGlobalLayout() {
    int buttonWidth = button.getWidth();
    button.setTranslationX(-buttonWidth); 
    button.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
  }
});
```

Hope this helps.